# jQuery Looping JSON Data

Tags: php, jquery, json, jsonp

I have created APIs to retrieve data from my server and then I get the data with json format like this :

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "2013-03-28": 1771,
        "2013-03-29": 1585,
        "2013-03-30": 1582,
        "2013-03-31": 1476,
        "2013-04-01": 2070,
        "2013-04-02": 2058,
        "2013-04-03": 1981,
        "2013-04-04": 1857,
        "2013-04-05": 1806,
        "2013-04-06": 1677,
        "2013-04-07": 1654,
        "2013-04-08": 2192,
        "2013-04-09": 2028,
        "2013-04-10": 1974,
        "2013-04-11": 1954,
        "2013-04-12": 1813,
        "2013-04-13": 1503,
        "2013-04-14": 1454,
        "2013-04-15": 1957,
        "2013-04-16": 1395
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I looping with my json data dynamically using jQuery?
My code :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url: "myurl.php",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success:function(data){
            if(data==''){
                alert('Fail');
            }else{
                alert('Success');   
            }
        }
    })
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I modify my jQuery to get data dynamically following the date that the data will change every day as in the example I wrote above data??
Thanks before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**jQuery.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) loop through the `items`

```
$.each(data.items[0], function (key, value) {
    console.log(key + ": " + value);
    var date = key;
    var number = value;
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wZARH/)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things to consider with your example data, but in your case, the following will do the trick:

```
var importantObject = data.items[0];
for(var item in importantObject ){
    var theDate = item;//the KEY
    var theNumber = importantObject[item];//the VALUE
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/JUz4G/1/)

But what does all this mean?...

First of all, we need to get the object that we want to work with, this is the list of dates/numbers found between a `{ }` (which means an object) - an array is defined as `[ ]`. With the example given, this is achieved like so:

```
var importantObject = data.items[0];
```

because `items` is an array, and the object we want is the first item in that array.

Then we can use the foreach technique, which effectively iterates all properties of an object. In this example, the properties are the date values:

```
for(var item in importantObject ){ ... }
```

Because we are iterating the properties, `item` will be the property value (i.e. the date bit), so item *is* the date value:

```
var theDate = item;//the KEY
```

Finally we get the number part. We can access the value of any given object property by using the string value of the property index (relative to the object), like so:

```
var theNumber = importantObject[item];//the VALUE
```

---

If you already know which date you want the value for, then you can access it directly like so:

```
var myValue = data.items[0]["2013-04-16"];//myValue will be 1395 in this example
```

Comment: What if I want to take apart the date and value in a string? I mean the key and its value is stored in a different string

Comment: @BerthoJoris: I have shown how to do this. `theDate` is the date/key and `theNumber` is the number/value

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jQuery each function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to do this. For example like this:

```
$.each(data, function(k, v) {
    // Access items here
});
```

Where `k` is the key and `v` is the value of the item currently processed.

Answer (score 1):

//get your detail info.

var detail = data.items[0];

$.each(detail, function(key, val) {

```
console.log(key + ": " + val);
```

}